# UiCollectionView cells issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an collectionview with various cells but I have a problem:

if I execute code on iPhone 6s simulator I get this (I want this on every device):

[image]

if I execute it on iPad Retina I get this:

[image]

and if I execute it on iPhone 5 (I dont see cells):
[image]

How do I solve this problem?
Can you help me?

//UPDATE:

if I remove all object in uicollectionviewcell (in this case only the image view) everything work fine (the cells are the same on iPad, iPhone 5 I see the cell) but naturally in the cell I havent objects

Comment: You need to provide more information. Show your data source methods, and tell us about the layout of your collection view.

Comment: what do you know in particular? I have only imageview in cell and I set image by code in cellForItemAt method

Comment: imageview has constraits

Comment: if it can ti help, I get this warning : the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.

Comment: Show us some code or storyboard configuration, how can we help you without that?...

Comment: it is: https://postimg.org/image/98j24th3z/

Comment: Please update your original post to put code or images here, not uploaded elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` to give a width equal to the collection view's width?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: /* your height */)
}
```

Comment: yes, I do simply that : return CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: 100)

Comment: screenWidth is a varuable that contains the screen's width

Comment: I tried to do like your reponse but I get the same result

Comment: Can I ask why you chose a collection view? A table view would always give you one cell per row and can be customized to look like you want.

Comment: Also, your view controller will need to implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol in order for sizeForItemAtIndexPath to be called.

Comment: if it can ti help, I get this warning : the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.

Comment: Ok, so maybe put some padding in there so that it's not quite the width of the screen? Perhaps screenWidth - 20 (or 50, or so on)? Did you set the collection view's insets? If so then subtract whatever number you put there.